# Download files from a server

Tags: c#, ftp, download, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to get a list of files on a server

CODE:

```
string ftpUserID = "user";
string ftpPassword = "password";
string ftpServerIP = "192.###.###.###";
string remoteDirectory = @"\Update\UpdateTest";
string localDirectory = @"C:\Updates";

string[] downloadFiles;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
WebResponse response = null;
StreamReader reader = null;

FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" +      remoteDirectory));
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
reqFTP.EnableSsl = true;
reqFTP.Proxy = null;
reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;
reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string line = reader.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    result.Append(line);
    result.Append("\n");
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
return result.ToString().Split('\n');
```

I keep getting the WebException error saying 'Unable to connect to the remote server'

This is as a result of errors in :

```
 FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" +      remoteDirectory));
```

Which is throwing a **System.NotSuportedException** on the **reqFTP.Content** and **reqFTP.PreAuthenticate** parts I think.

Comment: Try `reqFTP.EnableSsl = false;`?

Comment: FYI - you have forward and backward slashes in your final FTP url.

Answer (score 0):

You mention, though it is not visible in code, that you use `PreAuthenticate`.  This is not supported for FTP.

The `PreAuthenticate` property is provided only for compatibility with other implementations of the WebRequest and WebResponse classes, as per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.preauthenticate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).